# Datagrid add data dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am new to WPF and trying to add rows as data in `DataGrid`, i tried the following code, it adds rows but do not show text in rows.

I have an `XElement array` from which i want to loop `foreach` and add items in `DataGrid`
And after successful addition is there any way to assign an `ID` to rows of `DataGrid` so when i click on row, i could get the `ID` for that rows specified. Please guide.

**(Edit)** XElement Array Containing XML

```
[0] => <objective id="1" title="obj 1"> </objective>
[1] => <objective id="2" title="obj 2"> </objective>
[2] => <objective id="3" title="obj 3"> </objective>
```

Code i tried, adds empty rows in Grid:

```
var datagridTopic = new DataGrid {Width = 400, IsReadOnly = true};
//I only need one column
datagridTopic.Columns.Add(new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Topic",
    Width = datagridTopic.Width - 8 //after adding rows the grid gets scroll, so made column width lower
});

datagridTopic.Items.Add("obj 1");
datagridTopic.Items.Add("obj 2");
StackPanelContent.Children.Add(datagridTopic);
```

What i want to do is:

```
foreach (var element in XElement)
{
    string title = element.Attributes("title").ElementAt(0).Value; // obj 1
    datagridTopic.Items.Add(title);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding data to the datagrid using code, try to bind it with the datasource you have.

```
var datagridTopic = new DataGrid {Width = 400, IsReadOnly = true};
//I only need one column
var column1 = new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "ID",
    Width = datagridTopic.Width - 8 //after adding rows the grid gets scroll, so made column width lower
};
column1.Binding = new Binding("ID")
datagridTopic.Columns.Add(column1);

var column2 = new DataGridTextColumn()
{
    Header = "Title",
    Width = datagridTopic.Width - 8 //after adding rows the grid gets scroll, so made column width lower
};
column2.Binding = new Binding("Title")
datagridTopic.Columns.Add(column2);

var items = xElementArray.Select(x => new { ID= x.Attribute("id").Value, Title = x.Attribute("title").Value});


datagridTopic.ItemsSource = items; //set the data source for the grid to custom created items.

StackPanelContent.Children.Add(datagridTopic);
```

If you don't want to display the ID in your grid, then don't add the ID column, add only Title column. you will have to implement the MouseDown event for the rows and in that row you will find the DataContext of the row which will be your data item from which you can get the ID.

Comment: sorry for not clearing, i have updated my question plz check. ur solution cannot work bcoz i don't have any column name to put in binding constructor. and i have XML XElemets from which i have o query and put in grid

Comment: Hi as per your update, I have also updated my code. You can use linq with your XElement array to create a new collection of anonymous object which you can bind with your data grid.

Comment: Awesome thanks, i was not sure how to do it. many thanks. Can i assign The `id` as `tag` for the `row` and only `title` as text for row? so when i click the row, i could get the `id` for reference?

Comment: @Nithin Joshi can u tell how can i do that, following ur code plz